# Select max and min values in one sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

i have a table that has records with its timestamp. now i have a requirement to get the oldest record and the newest record

```
9/10/2014 6:54
9/10/2014 6:53
9/10/2014 6:51
9/8/2014 8:09
9/8/2014 7:00
9/5/2014 7:38
9/5/2014 3:57
9/5/2014 3:51
9/4/2014 11:09
9/4/2014 8:39
```

currently this is how i obtain them by sending two database calls which slows downs processing

```
$new_timestamp = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMP FROM $rectable ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1");
$col_old = mysql_fetch_assoc($new_timestamp);
$old = $col_new['TIMESTAMP'];

$new_timestamp1 = mysql_query("SELECT TIMESTAMP FROM $rectable ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC LIMIT 1");
$col_new = mysql_fetch_assoc($new_timestamp1);
$new = $col_new['TIMESTAMP'];
```

is there any way to optimize this code and fullfiill requirement without sending two database calls,  througha special query or a stored proceedure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `max` and `min` to get the newest and oldest timestamps

```
select max(timestamp), min(timestamp) from mytable
```

Comment: sorry its from the same table!!

Comment: you'll need to use uppercase "TIMESTAMP" and creating an index on TIMESTAMP will help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `UNION`

```
select TIMESTAMP as old FROM $rectracktable ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1
union all
select TIMESTAMP as new FROM $rectable ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: sorry its from the same table

Comment: It will also work if you got same tables. But, in that case @FuzzyTree's solution is more elegant. I thought you have two different tables.